# Drop IP fragments of a certain protocol

Tags: networking, iptables, traffic-shaping, mtu, traffic-filtering

When `conntrack` is active, the iptables stack never sees a fragmented IP packet, only the reassembled one ([source](http://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html)), so the `-f` test never matches.

If I want to block any fragment I could set `ipfrag_high_thresh` or 
`ipfrag_time` to 0 ([source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt)), but that would drop any kind of fragment. Is there anything I can do if I want to drop fragments of a certain IP protocol?

Answer (score 2):

I see two ways to achieve your goal, depending on your needs.

You can let reassembly run its course, then, after successful reassembly, drop the whole packet. This works only if the reassembled packet is over the interface MTU (otherwise you won't be able to distinguish between reassembled and “normal” packets). If the packets can’t be successfully reassembled they’ll get dropped anyway, but with a larger CPU overhead.

The other way is to modify the source, and make `nf_defrag_ipv4` ignore packets from the protocol(s) you want to handle directly. A quick glance suggests this should work, since there's already an option (`IP_NODEFRAG`) available for RAW sockets that lets you bypass the reassembly code.

To be honest, I too would love to have more control over this part of the filtering, so I’ll try to get a patch in to remedy the situation.

Comment: I think you should be looking at `tc` input filtering. You can do things before packets even hit the netfilter hooks.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but I can't port my ruleset to tc to avoid the mandatory defrag - after all, the stateful filtering is a core part of my setup. I also use other netfilter features to further classify the packets, not available in tc. BTW, did you solve your original problem? Did you use tc for that?

Comment: I used `tc`, in fact. There are also minimal performance improvements when early filtering in `tc`, see http://meat.pisto.horse/2014/10/iptables-microbenchmark-tc-performance.html

Comment: If you just want to drop packets based on a simple classification at extremely high speeds, you should to take a look at `netmap` - it can handle a 10gbit interface full of minimal sized packets with ease on a single core of a modern PC.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you can use the netfilter "raw" table, which comes before most of the connection tracking hooks. It has a "NOTRACK" target you can use to exempt certain packets from conntrack, or perhaps the `-f` condition itself would work with `--table raw`.

Comment: As long as `conntrack` is loaded, `-f` is always false, because the packet is always reconstructed.